# Selenium cannot type text

Tags: internet-explorer, object, selenium

I'm just starting using Selenium and facing this element

```
<object id="DebitCardNo_Ctrl" width="160px" height="20px" passwdctrl="false" onmousedown="this.focus();" tabindex="0" type="application/x-cmbedit">
```

Code that I used :

```
Actions actions = new Actions(browserDriver);
            actions.MoveToElement(browserDriver.FindElement(By.Id("DebitCardNo_Ctrl"))).Click().SendKeys("testing").Perform();
```

which I supposedly insert text into. 
I tried using sendKeys also click to element first then sendKeys but does not work. I'm using Selenium ver 2.46 with IE 10.

Does anybody face this before or might have idea about the problem ?

Thank you,

Comment: No error, just wont works. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to use try catch and debug code?

Comment: Yeap, didnt throw any exception. Thanks

Comment: What's your Selenium code you wrote?

Comment: Actions actions = new Actions(browserDriver);
            actions.MoveToElement(browserDriver.FindElement(By.Id("DebitCardNo_Ctrl"))).Click().SendKeys("testing");

Comment: pls tell us ur browser and its version and selenium version which u've added in classpath

Comment: I'm using selenium ver, 2.46 with IE 10. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We need more info, seeing how you are locating the element or your code would help.  Without more info, there isn't much we can do to help.  You can try the below.

```
driver.findElement(By.css("#DebitCardNo_Ctrl")).sendKeys("textToEnter");
```

Comment: Code that I'm using 

Actions actions = new Actions(browserDriver);
            actions.MoveToElement(browserDriver.FindElement(By.Id("DebitCardNo_Ctrl"))).Click().SendKeys("testing").Perform();